# How to Create This Curved Ridge?

Tags: modeling

I've got a simple cylinder and a sphere boolean, I'm trying to create a smooth ridge like in the following annotation. This seems like it would be pretty straight forward but I can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: a smooth ridge but with a "spike" as the blue line, that's it?

Comment: Not so much a spike, more as if the cylinder geometry was slightly pulled over the sphere boolean to create a lip partially around it. As if there was a bevel that joins the cylinder to the sphere.

Comment: more or less like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCL9q.png

Comment: Exactly like that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way to do it.

Start with a relatively low resolution for the cylinder and the sphere (16 rings here). Duplicate the mesh and apply the boolean on it.

[image]

Keep half of the object (we'll mirror it later), and simplify the mesh removing some edge loops in the sphere part and joining the vertices that are in proximity. Also add rings/cuts on the cylinder.

To do that, use these tools. Snap to vertices and automerge options:
[image]

Below before and after:

[image]

Make the cut for the ridge using the knife tool:

[image]

Add a mirror and subdivide modifiers. Push the ridge and bevel it.

[image]

For bottom and top part, make the faces and inset them:

[image]

Next step, cleaning, make quads from ngons and tris, for top and bottom parts:

[image]

To harden the ridge, you can select it and crease the edges:

[image]

That can give you this:

[image]

Blend file with each step included: [image]

Comment: This is fantastic, exactly what I wanted. There is a step in between the second from the bottom second lef and the bottom third left where the edges seem to go from quite angular to curved. Not sure how you managed to achieve that?

Comment: You're talking about the last steps? Just few "optimizations" a bit less vertices in the last one. No real impact for this shape.

Comment: One more question, I am trying to bevel that edge with CTRL but nothing seems to be happening at all. Are you using a plug in at all to create the bevel? I just can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I think bevel should work... and no, I used no plugins here. Is the issue visible in edit mode, or are you talking about the final result?

Comment: I'm talking about the bevel you mentioned here: "Push the ridge and bevel it." I think you may of dissolved some edges before you beveled? If that's the case, I got to here in the video, but looks very different to your bevel https://www.loom.com/share/ec684caba2cc4ed1819294e9c230ecce

Comment: Ah ok. after the bevel I've pushed the edge(s) to the right along X, to make a bigger ridge.